# Альтернатива VBMath.Rnd() в C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Рассматривал пример программы, в которой весь код написан на C#, а в одной функции используется фрагмент, написанный на VB. Вопрос в том, как перевести этот фрагмент также на С#?

```
public Cell getNeighbor()
{
    List<Cell> c = new List<Cell>();
    if (!(NeighborNorthID == "none") && Cells[NeighborNorthID].Visited == false)
        c.Add(Cells[NeighborNorthID]);
    if (!(NeighborSouthID == "none") && Cells[NeighborSouthID].Visited == false)
        c.Add(Cells[NeighborSouthID]);
    if (!(NeighborEastID == "none") && Cells[NeighborEastID].Visited == false)
        c.Add(Cells[NeighborEastID]);
    if (!(NeighborWestID == "none") && Cells[NeighborWestID].Visited == false)
        c.Add(Cells[NeighborWestID]);
    int max = c.Count;
    Cell currentCell = null;
    if (c.Count > 0)
    {
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBMath.Randomize();
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(Conversion.Int(c.Count * VBMath.Rnd()));
        currentCell = c[index];
    }
```

Comment: Какой-то декомпилированный кусок кода...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Точно! Особенно вот это: `!(NeighborNorthID == "none")`.

Comment: @VladD, это ж vb.net, а не vb.

Comment: Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBMath - этот кусок не "написан на VB". Он написан на C#. Это просто использование функции из сборки Microsoft.VisualBasic, в которой собраны классы для совместимости с VB6. Оставьте как есть, не надо его никак переписывать :)

Comment: @PashaPash, без подключения соответствующей сборки не скомпилируется ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну так стоит ее подключить :)

Comment: @PashaPash, а почему бы не переписать одну функцию?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что это рабочий семпл https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Maze-Generator-Recursive-136d3dcd/, C# версия, там уже все подключено и работает из коробки. Семпл древний, и вызов Rnd - это наименьшая из проблем в нем (например вот этот копипаст с NeighborWestID - это не результат декопмиляции, это реальный код :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [`VBMath.Rnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y66ey2hh(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает случайное число типа `System.Single` (то есть, `float` с точки зрения C#) между 0 и 1.

Для C# аналогичной функциональностью обладает [функция `NextDouble` класса `Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx). Учитывая вызов `Randomize()` перед вызовом `Rnd()`, нам необходимо инициализированное текущим системным временем случайное число.

Далее, конструкция `Convert.ToInt32(Conversion.Int(c.Count * VBMath.Rnd()))` выдаёт случайное целое число от 0 до `c.Count` (исключая верхнюю границу). Это достигается более простым методом на C#, т. к. равномерно распределённое целое число можно получить и прямо, без участия плавающей запятой:

```
var random = new Random(); // инициализирует текущим временем
int index = random.Next(c.Count);
currentCell = c[index];
```

---

Учтите, что результат будет не один-в-один таким же, как в с кодом на VB, т. к. алгоритмы подсчёта случайных чисел и использование seed в них отличаются. Тем не менее, поскольку речь идёт о *случайных* числах, повторение результата обычно и не нужно.

Comment: [`Conversion.Int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca22da04(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну да, Random.Next тоже выдаёт `int`.

Comment: Я просто чтоб ссылка была. А то у меня сначало возникло подозрение, что там округление, как при обычном VB'шном касте.

Answer (score 4):

`VBMath.Rnd()` - функция, возвращающая случайное число. В С# можете воспользоваться классом `Random`.

```
Random rnd1 = new Random();  
var randomNum = rnd1.Next();
```